# how to Calling function that has been defined in base activity in java android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, extends

How can I call a function that has been defined in base activity from other extend class?

For example my base class is "MainActivity":

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBar{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .
        .
        .
        SuperAwesomeCardFragment.newInstance(position,tabs.getJSONObject(position));
        .
        .
        .
    }
    public void showContent(Integer integer) {
        QuickContactFragment dialog = new QuickContactFragment();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "QuickContactFragment");

    }
}
```

And I defined SuperAwesomeCardFragment class in other file like:

```
public class SuperAwesomeCardFragment extends Fragment {
    public static  SuperAwesomeCardFragment newInstance(int position, JSONObject jsonTab) {
        SuperAwesomeCardFragment f = new SuperAwesomeCardFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
        b.putString(ARG_STRINGTAB, jsonTab.toString());
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .
    .
    .

        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
                MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
                m.showContent(getPostId(position));
            }
        }

    .
    .
    .
    }
}
```

When I call :

```
m.showContent(getPostId(position));
```

I faced this error :

```
08-15 03:24:19.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1342)
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:127)
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.sample.MainActivity.showContent(MainActivity.java:64)
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.sample.SuperAwesomeCardFragment$2.onItemClick(SuperAwesomeCardFragment.java:161)
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3285)
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1640)
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-15 03:24:19.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried to define static function in MainActivity but this is not solved my problem.

And also when I commented  this two lines:

```
public void showContent(Integer integer) {
    //QuickContactFragment dialog = new QuickContactFragment();
    //dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "QuickContactFragment");    
}
```

No problem and no error found.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Post the full error messages

Comment: did you relate your fragment in the layout with its main activity?

Comment: fragment is not my problem Meirav .calling showContent in Fragment is my problem.

Comment: Read the docs, in particular this page on fragment/activity communication: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: kcoppock your answer is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a listener, you can find an example of that [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#fragments_overview)

Comment: SuperAwesomeCardFragment is static then I can not passed MainActivity to Instantiate a Fragment.

Comment: Dave S:Thanks You for remember kcoppock's answer. your edit is not valid because when I use non static way, Fragment not support this.I use kcoppock's link to change my Fragment to ListFragment and use SampleListFragment list = new SampleListFragment();list.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

Comment: Ah yeah you are right fragments are static. Listeners are the way to go then.